# Missing "Bitmap" namespace in C# WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, namespaces

I need to use "Bitmap" from  namespace "System.Drawing" but there is nothing like this . If I create "Windows forms Application" there is not a problem like this.

How to use this "Bitmap" in my WPF project (add namespace that contains Bitmap class)?
I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC.

Comment: Add a reference to the `System.Drawing` assembly to your Visual Studio project. However, there is usually no need to use the System.Drawing.Bitmap class in a WPF application. WPF provides its own set of classes for handling bitmaps. Take a look at `BitmapSource` and derived classes.

Comment: Yes I know. But I also use AForge.net that needs to work on Bitmaps (to get image). Problem is that there is no Bitmap namespace in System.Drawing. Maybe the problem is with the new VS 2015 because I do not remember that i had previously that kind of problem with older versions.

Comment: So you added a reference to System.Drawing, then what happened???

Comment: Than I add Bitmap and there is showing error about missing namespace Bitmap. (when I try add System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap; etc it telling that there is no namespace Bitmap in System.Drawing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is my problem. System.Drawing not contain "Bitmap" namespace in
>   WPF project, but when i create Windows Forms application there is
>   Bitmap.

This is because WinForm has a reference to `System.Drawing` by default but WFP doesn't. So you need to add this reference manually (right-click on Solution Explorer ->  References -> Add Reference ... ).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this information:
namespace to use in your class file is System.Drawing
and refrence that you need to have is System.Drawing .

Namespace:  System.Drawing
Assembly:  System.Drawing (in System.Drawing.dll)

Comment: There is no `Bitmap` class in `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`.

Comment: Error what I got when I look on my created Bitmap element:
"The type or namespace "Bitmap" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
There is also no tip what I should add to solve it (only create new clase Bitmap)

Comment: yes you have to add refrence : System.Drawing click on refrence on your solution explorer and search for it. and add and then add the namespace

Comment: This is my problem. System.Drawing not contain "Bitmap" namespace in WPF project. (but when i create Windows Forms application there is Bitmap)

Comment: using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Comment: 1. Right click on properties of  Application.
2. Check Target framework
3. If it is .net framework 4.0 Client Profile than change it to .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: after changing to .NET Framework 4.0 (before was Framework 4.6) it now schowing no namespace Drawing  in System.Drawing.

Comment: read this article about framework4.6 and bitmap class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx